# Sort two data ranges in excel without affecting the first sort

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, format

I've got an active table with regularly changing data. Id like to sort column "I" (dates)for all blank values to be at the top.
Next, Id like all of the data under my blank values in "I" to then be sorted in column "J" as ascending.

Ideally, this means that my data will show all blank cells in column "I", and then everything under my last blank cell will then be sorted using column "J" (ascending).

(if I were to run my sort on column "J" after my sort on "I". My blank rows will be mixed into the data THIS IS NOT WHAT I WANT)
I need to find a way to ONLY sort my rows under my last blank cell in column "I".

Unfortunatley, this is only as far as I have got

```
Range("I:I").Sort Key1:=Range("J:J"), _
                     Order1:=xlAscending, _
                     Header:=xlYes
```

If you have any questions, please ask.

Thank you very much,

Matt

e.g.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, the sub below is not directly answer to your question, but maybe can help you to get started.

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim oldDt

'set range of the data/table (include header) into rg variable,
'(change the range as needed)
Set rg = Range("A1:C28")

'make an old date into oldDt variable
oldDt = "1-jan-1964"

'fill the rg column which row is blank with old date.
'(change the column number as needed)
rg.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = oldDt

'perform two level sort,
'(change the column number as needed)
With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=rg.Columns(1).Resize(1, 1), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=rg.Columns(2).Resize(1, 1), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange rg
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
End With

'format the date in the column into general,
'replace oldDt with blank,
'then bring back the expected date format,
'(change the column number as needed)
With rg.Columns(1)
    .NumberFormat = general
    .Replace What:=CDbl(CDate(oldDt)), Replacement:=""
    .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
End With

End Sub
```

Before run the sub:
[image]

After run the sub:
[image]